# @Value is null in thymleaf view

Tags: spring-boot, external, thymeleaf

I developped an application using spring-boot and thymeleaf as template. This is a screen shot

[image: Architecture]

I transfert an argument "url" from my controller like that

```
 ....
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView mav();
        mav.setViewName("list");
        mav.addObject("url", url);

        return mav;
    }
```

in my view "list.html" the value of url variable is always null

Woukd you have any idea ?

Comment: Paste your Thymeleaf template - how do you access this variable.

Comment: thanks maciej Walkowiak. I access to that variable like that:  <a target="_blank" th:href="@{${url}}"><p th:utext="${lblTest}" /></a>

Comment: I don't see any template in your code (there is nothing in the template directory!). Also post the full controller not a snippet and add your template.

Comment: I found the probem. The probelm was that I use url value in global variable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I found the probem. It was that I use url value in a global variable.

and the @Value

```
   @Value("${url}")
    private String url;

    private String testUrl = url 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView mav();
        mav.setViewName("list");
        mav.addObject("testUrl", url);  // here testUrl is null 

        return mav;
    }
```

then I change that by initialising testUrl inside the function list() and it works ;)